# How do I get place_id by using rails Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm using rails gem '[geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/)' on my rails application. Here is the code:

test.rb

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base

  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
    if geo = results.first
        obj.street = geo.street_address
        obj.city    = geo.city
        obj.state = geo.state
        obj.country = geo.country
    end
  end

  after_validation :reverse_geocode
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "tests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string    "street"
    t.string    "city"
    t.string    "state"
    t.string    "country"
    t.string    "place_id"
  end
```

After I create a Test model in rails console;

```
testLoc = Test.create(latitude: "49", longitude: "101")
```

it generates this Google Maps API: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=49.0%2C101.0&sensor=false

From there I can see that it has place_id.

> "place_id" : "ChIJnasu3tKddF0RqAvcjn5EhBE",

If I add this code to test.rb just below obj.country,

```
obj.place_id = geo.place_id
```

it returns NoMethodError: undefined method `place_id' for #

So, how could i get that place_id by adding some code to my Test.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse the JSON from Google API

```
parsed_response = JSON.parse(results.to_json)
```

Then, get the value from place_id

```
obj.place_id = parsed_response[0]["data"]["place_id"]
```

Comment: That works! Thanks @Mohammad, but I have another question regarding your answer. Why do I need to parse JSON to get the place_id?

Comment: Rails geocoder results does not provide that data. See http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails-geocoder/0.9.11 in Advanced geocoding